Using はず in a relative clause
I'm practicing using relative clause in Japanese and I'm stuck on how should I use はず in a relative clause. My sentence is as follows:

かぜをひいていて家にいるはずのみやさんは...

Should I use はずの or simply はず？

You always need の between はず and みやさん. This is because はず is technically a noun. Remember that a relative clause always modifies a noun; "かぜをひいていて家にいるはず" can modify はず because はず is a noun. And to connect the two nouns (はず and みやさん), you need to use の. (Note that はず is not technically in a relative clause. はず is outside the relative clause and is modified by the relative clause.)
